# Memory optimization / Interning in python

Tags: python-3.x, string, memory-management

Referring to the following output from the python:

```
>>> x=254
>>> y=254
>>> id(x)
2039624591696  --> same as that of y
>>> id(y)
2039624591696  --> same as that of x
>>> x=300
>>> y=300
>>> id(x)
2039667477936 ---> different than y when value exceeds a limit of 256 
>>> id(y)
2039667477968 ----> 
>>> str7='g'*4096
>>> id(str7)
2039639279632  ---> same as that of str8
>>> str8='g'*4096
>>> id(str8)
2039639279632 ---> same as that of str7
>>> str9='g'*4097
>>> id(str9)
2039639275392 ----> ---> content is same as that of str10 but address is different than that of str10
>>> str10='g'*4097
>>> id(str10)
2039639337008
```

Here, as I define the str9 as 'g'*4097 it takes a different memory address than the str10, it seems there is some limit here, now my  question is to find out these limits for the particular  python release.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @MD.RAKIBHASAN, I have updated the initial query, including an example of what I am trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

Which integers and strings that get automatically [interned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interning_(computer_science)) in Python is implementation specific, and has changed between versions.

Here are some principles and limits that seem to hold at least for my current installation (CPython 3.10.7):

All integers in the range [-5, 256] are automatically interned:

```py
>>> x = 256
>>> y = 256
>>> x is y
True
>>> x = 257
>>> y = 257
>>> x is y
False
```

CPython (version >= 3.7) also automatically interns strings if they are <= 4096 characters long, and only consist of ASCII letters, digits, and underscores. (In CPython versions <= 3.6, the limit was 20 characters).

```py
>>> x = "foo"
>>> y = "foo"
>>> x is y
True
>>> x = "foo bar"
>>> y = "foo bar"
>>> x is y
False
>>> x = "A" * 4096
>>> y = "A" * 4096
>>> x is y
True
>>> x = "A" * 4097
>>> y = "A" * 4097
>>> x is y
False
```

In some versions the rule was apparently to intern strings looking like valid identifiers (e.g., not strings starting with a digit), but that does not appear to be the rule in my installation:

```py
>>> x = "5myvar"
>>> y = "5myvar"
>>> x is y
True
>>> 5myvar = 5
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    5myvar = 5
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal
```

Additionally, strings are interned at compile time, not at runtime:

```py
>>> x = "bar"
>>> y = "".join(["b","a","r"])
>>> x
'bar'
>>> y
'bar'
>>> x is y
False
```

Relying on automatic string interning is risky (it depends on the implementation, which may change). To ensure a string is interned you can use the [`sys.intern()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.intern) function:

```py
>>> x = "a string which would not normally be interned!"
>>> y = "a string which would not normally be interned!"
>>> x is y
False
>>> import sys
>>> x = sys.intern(x)
>>> y = sys.intern(y)
>>> x is y
True
```